# Flutter: Why is my app crashing when I copy/paste into a TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, crash, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

I'm developing a desktop flutter app. Copy/pasting into a TextFormField seems to crash the app about 50% of the time. I don't get any error messages in the debug console, except for `Lost connection to device. Exited (sigterm)`. I can't find any information online similar to my issue, and I'm not even sure how to find the root cause of the issue. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code for the widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: widget.padded
          ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(13.0, 6.0, 13.0, 0.0)
          : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
            onChanged: widget.onTextChanged,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.hintText,
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13, vertical: 9),
            ),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
            maxLines: null,
            initialValue: widget.defaultText,
            expands: widget.expands,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

EDIT:
And here's an example of text which crashes the app every time.

```
* Name
Sarah

* Date
2022/10/05

* Topic
Animals + Pets<Speaking>

* New Language
wildlife <noun>||animals, birds, and plants living in their natural environment
fox <noun>||a wild animal like a dog with red-brown fur, a pointed nose, and a long, thick tail
red panda <noun>||an animal with reddish-brown fur and a long bushy tail that lives mainly in trees, especially in China and Nepal
owl <noun>||a bird with a flat face and large eyes that hunts small mammals at night
swan <noun>||a large, usually white bird with a long neck that lives on rivers and lakes
breed <noun>||to keep animals for the purpose of producing young animals in a controlled way

* Pronunciation
bear||be~r

* Corrections
Four day, we start running||On the fourth day, we started running
in this trip||on this trip
I meet a lot of new friends||I have met a lot of new friends
There are many house made by wood ||... made of wood//i\The difference between 'made from', 'made of', and 'made by' can be tricky, so let me know if you need any help with them!\
I saw them in long distance||I saw them from far away//I saw them from a distance
They are originally from Russian||... from Russia

===
```

EDIT: And here is the code for `widget.onTextChanged`:

```
onChanged: ((value) {
  if (_textController.text.endsWith('\n')) {
    // Add the prefix everytime a new line is created
    _textController.text += _linePrefix;
  }

  _text = value;
}),
```

Comment: pasting anything is triggering the crash or any specific content/text?

Comment: The text has a specific format I guess, but the contents are different each time. It seems to crash more with longer text though

Comment: can you add some of the sample data that is causing the crash also, mind adding code for the ``widget.onTextChanged``.

Comment: Will check and get back asap. Also, add code for the callback ``widget.onTextChanged``

Comment: Gotcha, thanks a bunch. I've added that too. Although just a note: I only just added the code to insert a new line prefix now, so before it was just `_text = value;`